# Nginx and Magento redirects

Tags: magento, nginx

Magento is running just fine on my Nginx + PHP-FPM stack, but I'm getting redirected to the home page every time I delete a product from the cart or add a tag on the product page.

I'm aware that replacing `$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));` with `$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');` on app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php 'fixes' the cart issue, but what about the tag one? Is there any rule I could add/improve on nginx.conf instead of hacking the Magento core? Strangely, that only happens on Ngix, not on Apache.

Here's an excerpt of my config:

```
        location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
            rewrite / /index.php;
        }

        location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
            rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
        }

        # Pass PHP scripts on to PHP-FPM
        location ~* \.php$ {
            if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
            #expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/spool/phpfpm.sock; ## php-fpm socket
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
            #fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
            include         fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking back as far as Magento CE 1.4.2, a stock Magento  `CartController.php` controller class doesn't have any code that looks like this

```
$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('/'));
```

I suspect you're dealing with an already hacked system.  I'd download a fresh installation and diff your `CartController.php` file.  Based on the information you provided my guess is someone replaced the following line

```
$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
```

with the line above that's causing your problems.

Comment: I was perusing at another forum and somehow copied the wrong code above - sorry. I can confirm that my install is fresh and with the "$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));" code. I really don't know why I'm having this issue. Any idea?

Comment: Really?  What version of Magento are you running?

Comment: Ah, this is funny. StackOverflow is somehow removing the asterisks from my pasted code above. Just to clarify: my app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php file does have the asterisks on 'getUrl'. I'm running on 1.6.1. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, ha, that makes more sense now.  Correcting that, nothing obvious jumps out.

Comment: Alan, while I don't find a solution for that, is there a way to make the product page point to itself - not the home - after adding a tag?